# Google Place Automplete box doesn't display anything

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm trying to implement a [Google places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?hl=FR) field on my website, but it doesn't work. I tried to copy/paste the sample given by Google on a *.html* file, it perfectly works, like other samples found on the web, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460723/google-places-autocomplete-with-marker) So I probably make a mistake on my project (ASP.NET MVC), but I don't know where...

Here is what I've done :

```
//Loading places library
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();

    //Some other asynchronous methods loading some partial views, but with no rapport with Google Maps
}

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = { /*various options*/ };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    //4 next lines are given by Autocomplete doc
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    /* Implementation of other tools, like 
     * DrawingManager
     * MarkerClusterer
     * and OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier 
     */

     //This event is given by google
     google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        console.log("place_changed"); // Never goes here
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
        }

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
        }
        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }
    });
}
```

And the HTML is just

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
```

This WORKS on a simple *.html* file. I can see the request to Google's servers in the "Network" tab of my console, like  :

[image: Network tab OK]

But in my project, the field appears with the placeholder, but when I type in, there's just ... Nothing. Like a simple text field. Anything in the console, just... anything, except the library places script which is correctly downloaded.

I tried to change `z-index`, but the problem is still the same. I also tried to put the `Autocomplete` field elsewhere on the page (not on the Google Map itself) it doesn't care.

I also tried to change the `$(document).ready` by `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` and the problem is ... the same !

Oh, and by the way, I also try with the [Autocomplete Search Box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=FR), the problem is **exactly** the same.

Is there something obvious I'm missing ? Something to activate in Google Developpers console, to include in my project, anything... I'm new to [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), so maybe I forget a fundamental thing ?

Comment: When I try the [Autocomplete Search Box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=FR) there is no problem

Comment: Also no problem with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/CQdk9/

Comment: You're right, absolutely no problem with the jsfiddle... So what can explain it isn't working ? The places library is correctly loaded. Is there anything able to block the request when I type into the Autocomplete field ?

Comment: Impossible to answer without more details(or a link).

Comment: Start by removing your custom placeholder, when no placeholder will be visible the creation of the autocomplete-instance wasn't successful

Comment: Just try to remove the placeholder, it still doesn't do anything. I'm sorry I'm developping on localhost so I can't provide any link (personal project). I'll try to reproduce the problem on a fiddle, with more code